# Не работает include в js. eel, python,js,html

Tags: javascript, python, html, eel

Работаю с либой eel для python. Сделал структуру папок в проекте. Пытаюсь соединить Js файлы из Methods папки в один main.js. Не работает include (Uncaught ReferenceError: include is not defined)
[image: Структура папок]

[image: Ввожу вот так]

[image: Вот ошибка]

Comment: А где сама функция `include` ?

Comment: Я не знаю. Она изначально в языке не доступна? Она же не самописная.

Comment: Не доступна. [Посмотри здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/import-export)

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень хорошая дока.

Comment: На здоровье! :)